# Gurobi-Python, unmet demand of customers

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, python, gurobi, supply-chain

I would like to capture the unmet demand by modeling the following constraint with two decision variables. where $QU_{wc}$ is the unmet demand and $QW_{wc}$ the shipped amount of products. I model the constraint correctly but its not giving me the value of $QU_{c} \;\forall \; customers$ which is a decision variable of the shortage.

$QU_{c}$ is the shortage quantity for all customers, which is a decision variable

$QW_{wc}$ is the amount shipped from $w$ to $c$.

$D_{c}$ demand at the customers for all customers.

Shortages are allowed.

$\sum_{w} QW_{wc} + QU_{c} \geq D_{c} \ ; \forall{c}$

Demand constraints

m.addConstrs(($QW_{wh}$.sum('*',c)+ $QU_{c}$[c] >= demand[c] for c in range (customers)),"Demand")$

Comment: What is $d_h$ and $h$?

Comment: @abde what's the issue? Unmet demand can be summed up in an expression like Total Unmet$ =\sum_h (D_h - \sum_w QW_{h,w})$. Then Unmet can be included in the objective.

Comment: @Sutanu I would like to get it as decision variable, for instance, if shortage is occurred, the unmet demand will be calculated for each customer and return it's value.

Comment: @Sutanu I tried the one that you have mentioned it is not working for me,

Comment: Ok, so unmet demand per customer if it occurs?

Comment: In the last line of your code you are making shipped demand $==$ demand. Make it $\le$. Or use the formula you yourself put in the question where you said shortages are allowed. Also make $0\le QU_{w,h}$. This will take unmet demand either a positive or 0 as you add in the objective.

Comment: @Sutanu, yes, you are correct, my previous formulation was wrong, I correct it.

Comment: @Abde, I will put my comment as answer of it has solved the problem

Comment: All my nonnegative constraints  are satisfied, however, when I add this $QU_{h}$ it makes the solver crazy, and I loose the decision variables that I got before!

Comment: @Sutanu it has not been solved, lol. please don't put as an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144570/discussion-between-abde-and-sutanu).